# When I use "echo" in vendor methods - products not showing, but work fine without it

Tags: category, event-observer, magento2.3, product-collection, category-products

I got the next code:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
        $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
    } else {
        $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
    }
    echo "Collection count".$collection->count();
    return $collection;
}
```

When I tried to echo collection count - it always equals 0, but when I delete this string - everything is okay count equals 16. How?

Comment: Try `count($collection->getData())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product collection empty on category page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278136/product-collection-empty-on-category-page)

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal thanks for the answer, but I want to know how it's works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to append the **`string`** in the **return**

```
//echo "Collection count".$collection->count();
$collection->count();
return "Collection count ".$collection;
```